# Rolling linear regression for use with groupby operation on a cuDF dataframe

Tags: numba, numba-pro, rapids, cudf

I would like to calculate the rolling slope of y_value over x_value using cuML LinearRegression.

Sample data (cuDF dataframe):

```
| date       | x_value | y_value |
| ------     | ------  |  ----   |
| 2020-01-01 | 900     | 10      |
| 2020-01-01 | 905     | 15      |
| 2020-01-01 | 910     | 15      |
| 2020-01-01 | 915     | 15      |
| 2020-01-02 | 900     | 30      |
| 2020-01-02 | 905     | 40      |
| 2020-01-02 | 910     | 50      |
| ------     | ------  | ------  |
```

A simple function to use LinearRegression:

```
def RollingOLS(x, y):
    lr = LinearRegression(fit_intercept = True, normalize = False, algorithm = 'svd')
    reg = lr.fit(x, y)
    
    return reg.coef_
```

What I would like to do:

```
data.groupby('date').rolling(2).apply(RollingOLS, x=x_value, y=y_value)
```

However, I am getting an error: `NotImplementedError: Handling UDF with null values is not yet supported`. Is there any way to overcome this error? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to resolve the error `NotImplementedError: Handling UDF with null values is not yet supported` please reassign `None/null` values to another value or remove the samples which have `None/null` values from your DataFrame.

Comment: Once you have resolved the above mentioned error I dont think your code will work. Please provide a reproducible version of the code to help with further analysis.